# FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter show by users uid

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I am using FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter and I'am trying to show post for the following users so I have used these method blew but It show posts if the post id is available at the following users:

Here's my json:

```
"Following" : {
    "ORBBKfZAAUhqI1h7ojQDzYOjgkp1" : { 
       "pypD1SYZkbcYesk09WuMUY1AkTf1": true,
       //When I add here post id it show the post ex:"-KduqnVVczZf5uibQiZ-" : true,//Post Shows Up
  },
  "Posts" : {
    "-KduqnVVczZf5uibQiZ-" : {
      "Describe" : "gg",
      "MostView" : -8,
      "Time" : 14881230655,
      "UID" : "pypD1SYZkbcYesk09WuMUY1AkTf1",
      "Username" : "Jone",
      "Wallpaper" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-3f4c5.appspot.com/o/Posts%2Fcropped906285501.jpg?alt=media&token=0c1a3a3d-6e48-4c4e-ba59-f5646bf8965f"
    },
    "-Ke5gJ00CxbjhOuhzLIx" : {
      "Describe" : "hajj",
      "MostView" : -9,
      "Time" : 1488318465,
      "UID" : "pypD1SYZkbcYesk09WuMUY1AkTf1",
      "Username" : "Dom",
      "Wallpaper" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-3f4c5.appspot.com/o/Posts%2Fcropped1717103943.jpg?alt=media&token=a85b2488-5ac7-49a7-9ad0-dbf4e6f29389"
    },
    "-KeCuiFmUCpN19zwsTsR" : {
      "Describe" : "a",
      "MostView" : -2,
      "Profile" : "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-suB77riNoX8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ADPlhfKMzINn-Ki538Sqf6SRGaXC81-WuQ/s200-c/photo.jpg",
      "Time" : 1488439652,
      "UID" : "z2SNUlLd6mQM8nnlkU2VUws5Ggl2",
      "Username" : "Dom",
      "Wallpaper" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-3f4c5.appspot.com/o/Posts%2Fcropped1913886685.jpg?alt=media&token=c8ad26b2-8f09-453b-b48a-aad9e4d8b5c3"
    },
    "-KeD2fBUQ09HVMrvAneb" : {
      "Describe" : "ee",
      "MostView" : -2,
      "Profile" : "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-suB77riNoX8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ADPlhfKMzINn-Ki538Sqf6SRGaXC81-WuQ/s200-c/photo.jpg",
      "Time" : 1488441999,
      "UID" : "z2SNUlLd6mQM8nnlkU2VUws5Ggl2",
      "Username" : "Dom",
      "Wallpaper" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-3f4c5.appspot.com/o/Posts%2Fcropped1904338270.jpg?alt=media&token=d200b7fc-15e7-4dc4-9913-59c377929e9e"
    },
    "-KeDfnMWiB7k_4J3FBgZ" : {
      "Describe" : "f12g",
      "MostView" : -1,
      "Time" : 1488452517,
      "UID" : "ORBBKfZAAUhqI1h7ojQDzYOjgkp1" 
      "Username" : "Young",
      "Wallpaper" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-3f4c5.appspot.com/o/Posts%2Fcropped1872832638.jpg?alt=media&token=80239844-a872-47e2-9689-92d368dd9452"
    },
    "-KeDfrw4inUQFtIDXJHp" : {
      "Describe" : "fg",
      "MostView" : -2,
      "Time" : 1488452536,
      "UID" : "ORBBKfZAAUhqI1h7ojQDzYOjgkp1" 
      "Username" : "Young",
      "Wallpaper" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-3f4c5.appspot.com/o/Posts%2Fcropped1872832638.jpg?alt=media&token=80239844-a872-47e2-9689-92d368dd9452"
    },

  }
}
```

And here's my method that I use:

```
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");
    mDatabaseFriends = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Following").child(mCurrentUser.getUid());

   FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter<Getting_Posts,PostViewHolder> firebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter<Getting_Posts, PostViewHolder>(
            Getting_Posts.class,R.layout.post_card_design,PostViewHolder.class,mDatabaseFriends,mDatabase.orderByChild("Username"))
    {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, Getting_Posts model, int position) {}};
```

I have used orderByChild method with the mDatabase but it doesn't work so I need to order or sort I posts by username so I couldn't find the correct query that can be used for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply sorting by updating your code like below:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Following").child(mCurrentUser.getUid()).orderByChild("Username");
```

Check Firebase doc for [Sort data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sort_data)

Comment: Ok @pRaNaY, and what about showing the posts for only following users

Comment: The mentioned link above also include how to filter data. In this case, you want to filter data of `Post` by using `uid` data inside it, right?

Comment: Sorry brothers, but I couldn't till now solve the issue.

Comment: @koceeng: yes, but these methods are filtering data with `orderby` method. As per @7uthaifah suggest, we need to get filtered **posts** for only **following** user. For that we need to come up with our own code(logic) to get only following users posts.

Comment: @7uthaifah: no sorry. Try to edit your question with new content if you tried any thing new after posted question. so it can help to solve problem.

Comment: All contents that can give the possible answer are in the question,  if anyone can till me how can I show posts by following user just give me the query or the method that can be used because I have worked for try to solve it for more than 3 week , but who cares